# Angular repeating radio button group in a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 'recommendations', an array of recommendation like:

```
{Id: 1, Label: "option 1"},
{Id: 2, Label: "option 2"}
```

And 'items', an array of item like:

```
{Id: 1, Name: "Name 1", Recommend: recommendations[0]},
{Id: 2, Name: "Name 2", Recommend: recommendations[1]}
```

Now I like to show a list of items, for each item, show item name and radio button group to let user select one of possible 'Recommend' options.

My html looks like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in viewModel.items">
  <div>
    {{i.Name}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Recommend this?</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="radio" ng-repeat="r in viewModel.recommendations">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="i.Recommend" ng-value="r"/>
                {{r.Label}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{i.Name}}, {{i.Recommend.Label}}
  </div>
</div>
{{viewModel.items | json}}
```

When I click one of options for each item, I see corresponding Recommend.Label is changing properly so it seems to be bound to model ok.

My problem is that, on initial page load, radio button group of each item is not showing the current option even though 'items' seems to have one of possible Recommend object. (All radio buttons are not checked).
What am I missing?

Comment: Would you like to setup jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the item's "Recommend" value to bound to $scope.recommendations at the beginning.

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.viewModel = {};
$scope.viewModel.recommendations = [{Id: 1, Label: "option 1"}, {Id: 2, Label: "option 2"}];
$scope.viewModel.items = [{Id: 1, Name: "Name 1", Recommend: $scope.viewModel.recommendations[0]}, {Id: 2, Name: "Name 2", Recommend: $scope.viewModel.recommendations[1]}]; });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkgetptj/

Comment: on page load, Recommend of each item is already set to first option in recommendations..?